# Weird characters in linux Konsole

Tags: linux, locale, oh-my-zsh, cinnamon

I´m running linux Konsole on top of Cinnamon graphical environment under zsh shell.

Here is the shot[image]

The .zshrc contains the following call:

```
autoload -U promptinit && promptinit
prompt fade
```

Graphical card:

```
~/ glxinfo -v | grep vendor
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
```

Any idea what´s wrong ???

Comment: They look like something gone wrong with ANSI sequences for setting colours. I would look to see what is setting PS1 etc in the various profile & rc files.

Comment: Does the same happen if you set your locale to `en_US.utf8`?

Comment: Same with en_US.utf8. Problem goes away if i switch to bash. @bib which files, it’s a single server with default config. I’m root on this server

Comment: Look at the man page for the shell to see which files it looks for.